# Running docker images inside an embedded system created via BuildRoot

Tags: docker, buildroot

I'm fairly new to both Docker and Buildroot.  I'm trying to launch a simple docker image (hello-world) from inside a basic embedded system which I created through one of the provided buildroot configurations.  Specifically, I'm using the provided qemu_x86_64_defconfig.  I've added the following modules through 'make menuconfig'

> BR2_PACKAGE_DOCKER_CLI=y BR2_PACKAGE_DOCKER_COMPOSE=y
> BR2_PACKAGE_DOCKER_ENGINE=y BR2_PACKAGE_CONTAINERD=y
> BR2_PACKAGE_RUNC=y

I am able to boot into my system via qemu, and launch docker; however, when I try and run the basic hello-world image, I get an error:

```
> docker run hello-world
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": x509: certificate 
signed by unknown authority.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Googling this particular error, all the suggestions seem to indicate issues with firewalls, proxy's, VPN connections, etc.  Some people point to instructions on adding security certificates, such as this:  https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/certificates/.  On the other hand, I have no issue installing and running the docker "hello-world" image in any of my standard Linux distributions (running via WSL), or on Windows itself.  My guess is that the error is unrelated to needing certificates and is a red herring for a different "buildroot embedded system" related issue.

Has anyone had any success running docker images inside a buildroot generated embedded system?  I found this old post which seems to be when docker support was still being patched into buildroot.  The latest 2022/2023 versions have these modules included it seems, though I'm not sure I've included all the necessary components for a working system.

Comment: Posted this on reddit as well, one comment that might be relevant:

Looks like it throws the error when you establish https to *.docker.io, maybe your system is missing the standard certificate store? Not sure how buildroot includes root certs but I would start looking there to validate whether or not you have them on your system.

Doesn't feel to me like a docker-specific problem.

Comment: Issue was that I need to install 
BR2_PACKAGE_CA_CERTIFICATES=y

Now I'm hitting this new issue

docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: seccomp: config provided but seccomp not supported: unknown.

Answer (score 2):

Final missing piece was to include LIBSECCOMP libraries.  Here's the full list of buildroot packages required to run the hello-world docker image inside a buildroot generated embedded image:

```
BR2_PACKAGE_LIBSECCOMP_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_LIBSECCOMP=y
BR2_PACKAGE_CA_CERTIFICATES=y 
BR2_PACKAGE_DOCKER_CLI=y 
BR2_PACKAGE_DOCKER_COMPOSE=y 
BR2_PACKAGE_DOCKER_ENGINE=y 
BR2_PACKAGE_CONTAINERD=y 
BR2_PACKAGE_RUNC=y
```